# Merge arrays with its count in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an array like this

```
A = [@"aa",@"cc",@"bb",@"bb",@"cc",@"aa",@"cc"]
```

I need to convert it to

```
A = [@"x2 aa",@"x2 bb",@"x3 cc"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Count the similar elements and create a new string, add it to new array. As shown here:

```
NSArray *aArray = @[@"aa", @"cc", @"bb", @"bb", @"cc", @"aa", @"cc"];

NSCountedSet *set = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:aArray];

NSMutableArray *countedArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *str in set) {
    [countedArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"x%ld %@",[set countForObject:str], str]];
}

NSLog(@"%@",countedArray);
```

***Output:***

> (
>       "x2 bb",
>       "x2 aa",
>       "x3 cc" )

Comment: Actually there's no needs to create counted set instance. The algorithm could be a much easier.

Comment: @lgor: Are you saying about your answer??? How that sets the counted number in x2, x3, x4 way???? Please try your answer and check the desired output as asked by OP.